# Find which UI Element the mouse is over

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, wpf-controls, winrt-xaml

How to find the UI Element which is directly over the mouse over point.

[image]

Here Experience Age, Experience Month are Custom controls.

How do i get the Experience Month UIElement?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the property `Mouse.DirectlyOver` (which returns `IInputElement`)to get your element.

Comment: this will get directly over element, but is there a way to get all the elements which is under the mouse point?

Answer (score 1):

```
VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(location, Panel);
```

This will get all the elements behind the location.

> this will not be in WPF. may it will be useful in Silverlight and WinRT.

Comment: If this is not valid for WPF, why is it marked as answer to a question in WPF category?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dependencyproperty in the custom control to know mouse is over the control or not.
Then handle the custom control's mouse move event and apply the depencey property to true value.

Regards,
Ramesh